# error CS1501: No overload for method `Sort' takes `0' arguments

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of strings into alphabetic order. I tried `s = s.Sort();` where a is the list but it gives the error `error CS1501: No overload for method`Sort' takes `0' arguments` I'm not passing it any arguments so why is it giving me this error?

Edit: s is `string[] s`

I tried using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) website to help

Comment: What arguments does `Sort()` take, according to Intellisense? It's objecting because there is no method matching that name which takes 0 (no) arguments, meaning it takes 1+ arguments, but you're not specifying any.

Comment: List<T>.Sort() is void, you can't assign the "sorted result" to a variable. If you want that use LINQ extension OrderBy()

Comment: It's telling you that you CAN'T pass zero parameters. So you need to look at the documentation for it to find out what it wants.

Comment: The List.Sort with no parameters is declared in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, check your usings / references. BTW, the object should implement the IComparable interface

Comment: It can't be `List.Sort()`, because that doesn't need any parameters. What is the full type of `s`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on you exception, you don't have a list, you have an array, probably `string[] s`. Try

```
Array.Sort(s);
```

Comment: This seems likely - you definitely get the OP's error message if `s` is an array rather than a List<T>.

Comment: I tried that but it gives the error `error CS0103: The name `Array' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @RoryDanes make sure you have the following using directives: `using System;` and 
`using System.Collections.Generic;`. Also, the reference you post is for the List<T> sort, for the array version, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This works but is there any way to sort an array with capitalized words coming first?

Answer (score -3):

The `Sort()` method returns `void`. It doesn't create new list of strings, it justs sorts the current list.

Insted of `s = s.Sort()` just call `s.Sort()`

Comment: If that was the case, it wouldn't throw a CS1501

Comment: If he really was trying to call `List<T>.Sort()` like that, the error would be `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'` (where `T` is the type of the list's elements).

Comment: Well, he didn't show us the whole code. The error must be somewhere else then. But from what he showed us, he used `s = s.Sort()`, and you shouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Please read [answer]. If the OP didn't show enough code, the question has to be closed, not answered based on guesses.

Comment: Ok, sorry then.

Comment: "*But from what he showed us, he used s = s.Sort(), and you shouldn't be able to do that.*". Yeah, but that wouldn't produce a CS1501, no? So your supposed answer is not even addressing the problem ;-)